# Time series data into df with equal intervals

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series

I have a DataFrame with Time Series Data looks like:

```
Date                Value
2019-02-10 00:00:00 9661
2019-02-10 00:00:19 9654
2019-02-10 00:45:20 9659
2019-02-10 01:01:20 9649
2019-02-10 01:30:18 9712
```

Is there a simple way to convert the data to equal intervals? (every 15 minutes to be exact)

each time step will get an average of the values within the step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with `mean`:

```
print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2019-02-10 00:00:00', '2019-02-10 00:00:19',
               '2019-02-10 00:45:20', '2019-02-10 01:01:20',
               '2019-02-10 01:30:18'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)

df = df.resample('15Min').mean()
print (df)
                      Value
Date                       
2019-02-10 00:00:00  9657.5
2019-02-10 00:15:00     NaN
2019-02-10 00:30:00     NaN
2019-02-10 00:45:00  9659.0
2019-02-10 01:00:00  9649.0
2019-02-10 01:15:00     NaN
2019-02-10 01:30:00  9712.0
```

For missing intervals get misisng values, so if necessary remove it use [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = df.resample('15Min').mean().dropna(how='all')
print (df)
                      Value
Date                       
2019-02-10 00:00:00  9657.5
2019-02-10 00:45:00  9659.0
2019-02-10 01:00:00  9649.0
2019-02-10 01:30:00  9712.0
```